# alert message not appearing from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am trying to send information to the database using ajax such that the browser does not load when a user favorites a message. the data is being sent to the db and everything is fine, but i am still getting the reload of the page and the alert message i am trying to print is not being printed

the id and values:

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console? Do you see the network request?

Comment: p tag really does not have a value property. You really should use data attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect is probably because you use `a` tag and you don't use event.preventDefault.

```
<a class="msg-icon" onclick="event.preventDefault();ajaxfav()"><img src="images/linedfav.png" id='img'></img></a>
```

Comment: there is no href so doubt it

Answer (score 0):

A `<p>` tag does not have a `value` property. So when you reference it, you will get undefined. So you can not just use `.value` to reference the attribute like you can with inputs.

You should use a data attribute and access it with dataset. You can access it by getAttribute, but it is better to use a data attribute with dataset.

```js
console.log('value: ', document.querySelector("#p1").value)
console.log('data: ', document.querySelector("#p1").dataset.value)
console.log('attr: ', document.querySelector("#p1").getAttribute("value"))
```

```html
<p id="p1" value="hello" data-value="world"></p>
```